# Why are data cropped in a dataset?

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

Why are data cropped in a dataset?
HTML

```
<div id="osName" data-osname = <%= system.os %>></div> //system.os ="["Windows10","Windows7","LINUX7","MAC OS13"]" - JSON
```

JS

```
let osname = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('osName').dataset.osname); //syntaxerror unexpected end of json
```

Because

```
console.log(document.getElementById('osName').dataset.osname); //"["Windows10","Windows7","LINUX7","MAC
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why? because you are not adding quotes around the attribute and it breaks on the whitespace

```
<div id="osName" data-osname='<%= system.os %>'</div>
```

```js
console.log("without", document.querySelector("#test1").dataset.foo)
console.log("with", document.querySelector("#test2").dataset.foo)
```

```html
<div id="test1" data-foo=["asdf","foo bar"]></div>
<div id="test2" data-foo='["asdf","foo bar"]'></div>
```